# JAVA GUI Layout - what is best layout for 6 buttons placed vertically with spaces?

Tags: java, user-interface, layout

I have been recently creating some GUI's for my program. However for my next GUI I want to know what is the best way to create a frame as follows:

It will have a title, Hotel Menu and then under it I want it to have 6 buttons placed vertically with spaces in between them. Wondering what is the best layout I can use to achieve such a thing?

I have used box layout before, but the buttons were uneven sizes and stuck together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What IDE you are using?! You can use NetBeans as IDE, it has the advantage of the classical "click-and-drag" GUI design. Else, if you want to manually write the coding, the best way is to use Grid Layout. You can read more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

Comment: I am currently using Eclipse, What I was struggling on is how to make spaces between buttons

Comment: What you can do, download NetBeans, design your GUI freely there, and then, you can manually import (copy-paste) your code from NetBeans to your Eclipse. It'll work normally. This isn't an ethical way, but it saves you the time going through the hustle and bustle manual GUI design in Eclipse.

Comment: Oh that sounds very nice, I will be downloading NetBeans then. Thanks